# Entity reference field definition to auto create entities

Tags: 8, entities

I have a field definition set up like below. I want Drupal to do all the heavy lifting for me, so my definitions are minimal and rely on Drupal defaults:

```
    $fields[$field] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
        ->setSettings([
            'target_type' => 'target_entity',
            'handler' => 'default',
            'handler_settings' => [
                'auto_create' => true,
            ],
        ])
        ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
            'weight' => $weight,
        ));
    ;
```

`target_entity` is just a simple bundleless entity.

This creates an entity reference auto-complete field in forms, but if I type something that doesn't match any existing entities, Drupal will say that no matching entities found and will refuse to create a new one.

How do I make the `auto_create` setting work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'you cannot auto-create bundle-less entities in Drupal 8.2.0. I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but you have to have a bundle for target entity ('all_target_entities' in my example) and indicate that as target bundle in the settings:

```
$fields[$field] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
    ->setSettings([
        'target_type' => 'target_entity',
        'handler' => 'default',
        'handler_settings' => [
            'auto_create' => true,
            'target_bundles' => [
                'all_target_entities' => 'all_target_entities',
            ],
        ],
    ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'weight' => $weight,
    ));
;
```

I think it was not the case up to some point, so stating the exact version I am having this issue with.

Comment: You should open a core issue in the entity_reference component with this.

Comment: The issue already exists: https://www.drupal.org/node/2821352

Comment: Yeah, saw that, but it doesn't explicitly say it's a bug, just says it's unnnecessary. Probbaly because no one knows if this was the intention or not - there is no documentation for this feature.